# Why css class not working inside the ion-toolbar?

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I'm creating Ionic 4 Angular app, and creating header section.in the header section i'm using ion-toolbar.when i has been use css class test in ion-icon but css class not working.below given stackblitz link.

[my ion-toolbar example, see home page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rngada)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the correct css file for your page.
For example in home.ts, change the @Component block to the following and it will work correctly

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.css']
})
```

Comment: actually my aim only showing my code from stackblitz as am given, i'm use this code and css not apply properly in ion-toolbar.i'm use stackblitz because code  snipped not showing icon. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one  styleUrls: ['/home.css']